# Is there a way to run GLM.from_formula without the intercept (PyMC3)?

Tags: python, glm, pymc3, patsy

This may be a dumb question but I've searched through pyMC3 docs and forums and can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to create a linear regression model from a dataset that I know a priori should not have an intercept. Currently my implementation looks like this:

```
formula = 'Y ~ ' + ' + '.join(['X1', 'X2'])

# Define data to be used in the model
X = df[['X1', 'X2']]
Y = df['Y']

# Context for the model
with pm.Model() as model:
    # set distribution for priors
    priors = {'X1':     pm.Wald.dist(mu=0.01),
              'X2':     pm.Wald.dist(mu=0.01) }
    
    family = pm.glm.families.Normal()
    
    # Creating the model requires a formula and data
    pm.GLM.from_formula(formula, data = X, family=family, priors = priors)
    
    # Perform Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling
    trace = pm.sample(draws=4000, cores = 2, tune = 1000)
```

As I said, I know I shouldn't have an intercept but I can't seem to find a way to tell GLM.from_formula() to not look for one. Do you all have a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to try Bambi https://github.com/bambinos/bambi If you want to work with GLMs. It is a higher-level wrapper on top of PyMC3 that makes it easier to work with Bayesian GLMs in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually puzzled that it does run with an intercept since [the default in the code for `GLM.from_formula`](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/v3.11.0/pymc3/glm/linear.py#L227) is to pass `intercept=False` to the constructor. Maybe it's because the `patsy` parser defaults to adding an intercept?

Either way, one can explicitly include or exclude an intercept via the patsy formula, namely with `1` or `0`, respectively. That is, you want:

```python
formula = 'Y ~ 0 + ' + ' + '.join(['X1', 'X2'])
```

Comment: I also thought the default was to omit an intercept. But this worked perfectly. Thanks!